# How do the two styles of tripod mount strap connectors compare?

Tags: camera-straps

I've been researching those cross body straps and while there is quite a difference in price and quality of the strap, I find it hard to find reviews comparing the different positions of the connector on the tripod mount.

There are two distinctive styles:

- The small ring:
  [image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/nkolus/5889502708/]
- The big plate which retains the tripod mount hole:
  [image: http://archetyped.com/lab/carry-speed-camera-sling-cs-2b-day-one/]

While an advantage of the second one is that you could still use your tripod I'm wondering if the different angle onto your body makes a difference?

Thus my question: is there any review comparing these kinds of connectors? Or is there someone here who has compared these?

Comment: There's a third kind. The tripod plates for Manfrotto tripods include a D-ring for tightening the screw which also acts as a connector for the strap:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/CE3ZL.jpg

Comment: @Nick I always thought manfrotto and others did not like it when you used their product that way?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that; I know it's not the primary purpose of the D-ring but it did help solve a problem for me...

Comment: They can't really stop you. And why would they not like you using it that way, it just makes their product look more useful, and therefore more sellable.

Answer (score 3):

The first image is of the [Black Rapid FastenR-3](http://www.blackrapid.com/product/hardware/fastenr3/).  It is designed to work with the other Black Rapid components, specifically the ConnectR-2 and the R-Strap. The main advantage of this type of strap is the quick movement along the R-Strap, allowing the user to grab the camera from waist height and pull it up to your eye quickly and smoothly. This is the main selling point of the Black Rapid system.

Other options to consider include the [Spider Holster](http://www.spiderholster.com/), which has its own unique mounting plate and strap system, while still allowing tripod use.

From your question it sounds like you are concerned with **how the mount will sit on your body**, and this is not only a function of which tripod mount you choose, but which strap you choose as well. More specifically, you are really comparing the different models from all different camera strap manufacturers. **It isn't so much the tripod mount that matters, it is the entire design of the strap system that matters.**

If you need to quickly switch between shooting handheld and shooting from a tripod, you might want a unit that is compatible with a quick release system such as a Manfrotto RC2 Quick Release Plate. If you like to carry the cameras around your waist, the Spider Holster might be your favorite choice. If you like to carry the camera(s) around your shoulder/neck then the Rapid Strap might be your unit of choice.

**It really comes down to personal preferences**:

- Type of photography you do
- How many bodies you carry
- How heavy are the bodies/lenses
- Shoulder/neck, Waist, back, wrist
- Do you frequently switch to a tripod

Some photographers even mix and match these systems, and find the most comfortable solution is one around the neck and one at the waist.

Overall, I think the best system is going to be determined by personal preferences and fit characteristics. Each of our bodies are different, and many of us have different camera setups, weights, and usage.

Additional Reading: [Spider Holster Review](http://www.revellphotography.com/blog/2010/07/review-the-spiderpro-camera-holster-system/)

Comment: okay, instead of comparing specific products, I tried to discuss the different type of systems. While the first image is of a blackrapid, there are other cross chest strap manufactures with a very similar system (sun spider, custom dslr). And others such as carry speed which have the mounting plate. Assuming their all interchangable (most of them are all on a single band around your body) I was wondering how the mounting style effects the position to your body. And was wondering if there is a big review somewhere comparing the different systems instead of just one.

Comment: Davy - I purposely tried to emphasize the fact that this is all a personal preference question in my mind. The lenses you use, the body, number of bodies, type of photography, etc - it all will change the decision you make.  Although, I did find one link which I didn't include originally, this might help you: http://www.dyxum.com/dforum/comparing-camera-strap-systems-review_topic69894.html
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed my preferred option isn't mentioned: use a clamp. You attach a standard Arca-Swiss style plate to the camera, and you screw the connector for the strap into the clamp. you can then quickly switch between carrying the camera on the strap and a tripod without reconfiguring or having to change clamps, and the quick release works on both ends. Also you can get good clamps for not a lot of money, and it makes your strap workable for every camera you might own.

[http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Lpc7ff12L.*SX522*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Lpc7ff12L._SX522_.jpg)